# Defining ideal gas isothermal compressibility as [density]/[pressure]?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

I came across an equation relating ideal gas mass flow rate to pressure drop, and in this relation the term $\beta$ is used and is defined in the nomenclature as:

> $\beta$ = ideal gas isothermal compressibility (gm/cc/psi).

As seen, the units for this $\beta$ as defined are of [density]/[pressure]. The equation where this $\beta$ is used is dimensionally consistent. I'm just not sure about the name "compressibility" being given for this term, $\beta$. I've only ever seen compressibility defined as:$$\beta_T = - ~\frac{1}{V} \left(\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}\right)_T = \frac{1}{\rho} \left(\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p}\right)_T$$

which would have units of [pressure]^-1.

Question: is it valid to define compressibility so that it has units of [density]/[pressure]? If 'yes', how does one arrive at that definition (what are the arguments and mathematical steps)?

Comment: The author of the article just chose to define it in that way (for his specific system and situation).  It is unconventional, and your is the more conventional definition.

Comment: @ChetMiller upvoted, I accept as answer.